# Print 2d list as a game board

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d list [1,2,3,4],[4,3,3,1],[3,2,1,1],[2,2,2,1] and I want to print it out to match the following format.

```
  0123
XXXXXXXX
0*1234*0
1*4331*1
2*3211*2
3*2221*3
XXXXXXXX
  0123
```

It should not be hard coded and the length of the list = n so this list n=4 but if list n=5 there would be 5 digits per row and the number on the sides would go 0,1,2,3,4.

So far all I have is:

```
for row in board:
    for column in row:
        print(column, end="")
    print("")
```

Which only outputs the list as:

```
1234
4331
3211
2221
```

please help me add all the special stuff.

Comment: What specific issues are you having adding that "special stuff"?

Comment: If the logic should be dynamic; 1) Why is a five element array 0,1,2,3,4 rather than 1,2,3,4,5 as this would follow the current logic? 2) What is the logic for determining the base arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Probably an unpopular opinion, but I think these kinds of problems are really fun.

This solution formats the contents correctly, even if you change the number of rows, and even the number of items in each row.

```
def draw_board(board):
    # determining the number of elements in a row, 
    # this is used for printing the X's
    # and printing the spaced ranges (i.e. "  0123  ")

    n = len(board[0])

    # calculating the total width of the board, 
    # + 4 is because of the "0*...*0" situation
    width = n + 4
    # calculating margin of the spaced ranges 
    # (i.e. calculating how much space on each side)
    margin = int(n / 2)

    # printing the spaced ranges using the margin
    print(" " * margin + "".join(str(num) for num in list(range(n))) + " " * margin)

    # printing the XXXX
    print("X" * width)

    # printing the row index number, 
    # with the *, 
    # along with the numbers in the row, 
    # followed by the * and the row number
    for row in range(len(board)):
        print(str(row) + "*" + "".join(str(elem) for elem in board[row]) + "*" + str(row))

    # printing the XXXX
    print("X" * width)
    # printing the spaced ranges using the margin
    print(" " * margin + "".join(str(num) for num in list(range(n))) + " " * margin)

b = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [4,3,3,1],
    [3,2,1,1],
    [2,2,2,1]
]

draw_board(b)

# OUTPUT:
#   0123  
# XXXXXXXX
# 0*1234*0
# 1*4331*1
# 2*3211*2
# 3*2221*3
# XXXXXXXX
#   0123
```

Edited to remove my own tests and to reflect given problem.

Comment: Friendly suggestion: Perhaps use fstrings (or basic string formatting) rather than string concat by ‘+’.  Will provide a cleaner syntax.

Comment: wow thank you soooo much. You explained everything so clearly. I thought it was so much more complicated. Thank youuuuu.

Comment: no problem @unknownswagger, glad I could help, was a fun problem!

Answer (score 0):

so I find a solution for what you want to do however I think it can be improved a lot (not program quite a lot in python), but I'll leave it here anyways :)

```
print("  ", end="")
for x in range(len(board)):
    print(x, end="")
print()

for x in range(len(board)+4):
    print("X", end="")
print()

for num,row in enumerate(board):
    print(f"{num}*", end="")
    for column in row:
        print(column, end="")
    print(f"*{num}", end="")
    print("")

for x in range(len(board)+4):
    print("X", end="")
print()

print("  ", end="")
for x in range(len(board)):
    print(x, end="")
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for the first line you pretty much print 2 spaces, followed by all the digits between 0 and the number of columns in your board. You can use the "range" function for this. Then you must print the correct amount of 'X'. The correct amount is number of columns + 4, I think you can see why.

You should keep a counter starting from 0. For each row you print, you must print the string value of the counter, followed by an asterisk(*), followed by your row, followed by an asterisk(*) and finally followed by the same counter value. You must increment the counter by one for each row.

The last 2 rows are the same as top 2.

I do not want to share my code because this is such a simple problem, I think solving it on your own will help you in the long run.